# dplyr summarise and then summarise_at in the same pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

This question has come up before and there are some solutions but none that I could find for this specific case. e.g.

```
my_diamonds <- diamonds %>% 
  mutate(blah_var1 = rnorm(n()),
         blah_var2 = rnorm(n()),
         blah_var3 = rnorm(n()),
         blah_var4 = rnorm(n()),
         blah_var5 = rnorm(n()))

my_diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarise(MaxClarity = max(clarity),
            MinTable = min(table), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(contains('blah')), mean)
```

Want a new df showing the max clarity, min table and mean of each of the blah variables. The above returned an empty tibble. Based on some other SO posts I tried using mutate and then summarise at:

```
my_diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(MaxClarity = max(clarity),
            MinTable = min(table)) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(contains('blah')), mean)
```

This returns a tibble but only for the blah variables, MaxClarity and MinTable are missing.

Is there a way to combine summarise and summarise_at in the same dplyr chain?

Comment: Dam, sorry gimme one sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue with the `summarise` is that after the first call of `summarise`, we get only the columns in the grouping  i.e. the 'cut' along with and the summarised columns i.e. 'MaxClarity' and 'MinTable'.   In addition, after the first `summarise` step, the grouping is removed with `groups = 'drop'`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.0
my_diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarise(MaxClarity = max(clarity),
            MinTable = min(table),
            across(contains('blah'), mean, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: Beautiful, never knew about across. Thank you!